# Tensorflow's DNNLinearCombinedClassifier prints regression loss instead of classification loss

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying Tensorflow's `DNNLinearCombinedClassifier` (version `1.3`) on the [Kaggle's Credit Card Fraud](https://www.kaggle.com/dalpozz/creditcardfraud) (classification) dataset:

```
m = tf.estimator.DNNLinearCombinedClassifier(model_dir='/.../model', dnn_feature_columns=deep_columns,
                                            dnn_hidden_units=[20,5])

def input_fn(df, num_epochs):
    return tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(
        x = df,
        y = df.Class,
        batch_size = 1000,
        num_epochs = num_epochs,
        shuffle=False)
```

with model's output (here *df.Class*) as a binary feature.
Tensorflow's logs on training

```
m.train(input_fn(data, 3))
```

are:

> INFO:tensorflow:**loss = 532.633**, step = 2566
> INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 37.9815 INFO:tensorflow:loss =
> 560.574, step = 2666 (2.635 sec) INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 38.3186

What is the loss function being used here?

Answer (score 1):

> What is the loss function being used here?

In case of binary classification, it's `_BinaryLogisticHeadWithSigmoidCrossEntropyLoss` - an internal wrapper around  [`tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits) loss function. You are confused by a large value, but if you look closely at what this function computes, you'll see that large values are quite possible.

If `x` are the logits and `z` are the labels (a single example), then the loss is equal to `x - x * z + log(1 + exp(-x))`, which is comparable to `x`, when `z == 0`. The total training loss is defined as the sum of losses over the mini-batch. Your `batch_size = 1000` and the data has ~30 features, so the training loss around `550` pretty much makes sense.

Take a look at this miniature example:

```
feature_columns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column("x", shape=[1])]
estimator = tf.estimator.DNNLinearCombinedClassifier(dnn_feature_columns=feature_columns,
                                                     dnn_hidden_units=[20, 5])

x_train = np.array([100., 20., 300., 40.])
y_train = np.array([0, 1, 0, 1])

input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    {"x": x_train}, y_train, batch_size=4, num_epochs=None, shuffle=True)
train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    {"x": x_train}, y_train, batch_size=4, num_epochs=1000, shuffle=False)
estimator.train(input_fn=input_fn, steps=1000)
```

Here's an output when I run it:

```
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 32.7514, step = 1
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 30.5939
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 18.7906, step = 101 (3.099 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 32.3183
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 15.5917, step = 201 (1.175 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 88.6797
```

You can imagine that changing the `batch_size` from `4` to `1000` can lead to a loss around `8000`. So, in conclusion, there's nothing to worry about this loss value.

Answer (score 0):

According to the original publication of [deep-and-wide learning](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.07792.pdf) they use logistic loss function for joined training. More specifically, model implementation relies on cross entropy loss applied to softmax output.

They use weighted sum to combine log-odds from two models before applying logistic regression.

Loss declaration can be found in the source code [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/python/estimator/canned/dnn_linear_combined.py):

```
...        
head = head_lib._multi_class_head_with_softmax_cross_entropy_loss(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
              n_classes,
              weight_column=weight_column,
label_vocabulary=label_vocabulary)
```

Comment: But `softmax` loss doesn't explain loss values of ~500.

Comment: @kamalbanga, `softmax` is just a normalizaing layer. Logits is the actual loss function. that is capable of mapping [0, 1]^N output into a the real number space [-inf, +inf]. Loss values of 500 are not unusual